# How do I count user input in Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, count, counter

The code for VB:

```
For 'I think this where the counter would go if I knew how to write it
        If (intEmpCount < 10) Then
            If decTotalTax < decGrossPay Then
                decNetPay = decNetPay
                boxResults.Items.Add("EMPLOYEE ID: " & dblEmpID.ToString)
                boxResults.Items.Add("Gross Pay: $" & decGrossPay.ToString("N2"))
                boxResults.Items.Add("Net Pay: $" & decNetPay.ToString("N2"))
                boxResults.Items.Add("State Withholdings: $" & decStateTaxAmount.ToString("N2"))
                boxResults.Items.Add("Federal Withholdings: $" & decFederalTaxAmount.ToString("N2"))
                boxResults.Items.Add("FICA Withholdings: $" & decFICAAmount.ToString("N2"))
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("ERROR. THE AMOUNT OF WITHOLDINGS ($" & decTotalTax.ToString("N2") & ") EXCEEDS THE GROSS PAY.")
            End If
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("ERROR. YOU HAVE EXCEEDED THE ALLOWABLE NUMBER OF EMPLOYEES.")
        End if
```

The question to be answered: How do I count how many EmployeeIDs have been entered?

For this assignment I am going under the assumption that the professor wants us to limit the number of employees to 10, so I'm trying to figure out how to do that. Also for the purpose of this assignment we should assume that the EmployeeID can be any number up to six or seven digits long dependent upon the size of the company.

For instance: 1000 10001 100001 101000 etc etc...

Comment: Add them to a `Collection` or some other container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the general syntax for a for loop in Visual Basic:

```
For counter [ As datatype ] = start To end [ Step step ]  
    [ statements ]  
    [ Continue For ]  
    [ statements ]  
    [ Exit For ]  
    [ statements ]  
Next [ counter ]
```

So your loop might look something like

```
For number As Integer = 0 To 5
            (something here)
        Next
        (something here)
```

So this means that we're declaring an integer called number that is = to 0 initially. It will keep going till it hits 5. You will write something similar but you will have to figure out your condition for when the loop is over (for example yours might be 10). I haven't coded in VB for awhile, but I mainly do C# which is somewhat similar. Your code might look like:

```
    For k As Integer = 0 To 5
            If (intEmpCount < 10) Then
                If decTotalTax < decGrossPay Then
                    decNetPay = decNetPay
                    boxResults.Items.Add("EMPLOYEE ID: " & dblEmpID.ToString)
                    boxResults.Items.Add("Gross Pay: $" & decGrossPay.ToString("N2"))
                    boxResults.Items.Add("Net Pay: $" & decNetPay.ToString("N2"))
                    boxResults.Items.Add("State Withholdings: $" & decStateTaxAmount.ToString("N2"))
                    boxResults.Items.Add("Federal Withholdings: $" & decFederalTaxAmount.ToString("N2"))
                    boxResults.Items.Add("FICA Withholdings: $" & decFICAAmount.ToString("N2"))
                Else
                    MessageBox.Show("ERROR. THE AMOUNT OF WITHOLDINGS ($" & decTotalTax.ToString("N2") & ") EXCEEDS THE GROSS PAY.")
                End If
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("ERROR. YOU HAVE EXCEEDED THE ALLOWABLE NUMBER OF EMPLOYEES.")
            End if
Next
```

**ALTERNATIVELY**

If you want though, you could create an integer variable BEFORE the for loop, and each time it iterates through add +1 onto it. So you might try something like:

```
Dim k As Integer = 0
    For 'I think this where the counter would go if I knew how to write it
            If (intEmpCount < 10) Then
                If decTotalTax < decGrossPay Then
                    decNetPay = decNetPay
                    boxResults.Items.Add("EMPLOYEE ID: " & dblEmpID.ToString)
                    boxResults.Items.Add("Gross Pay: $" & decGrossPay.ToString("N2"))
                    boxResults.Items.Add("Net Pay: $" & decNetPay.ToString("N2"))
                    boxResults.Items.Add("State Withholdings: $" & decStateTaxAmount.ToString("N2"))
                    boxResults.Items.Add("Federal Withholdings: $" & decFederalTaxAmount.ToString("N2"))
                    boxResults.Items.Add("FICA Withholdings: $" & decFICAAmount.ToString("N2"))
                    k += 1
                Else
                    MessageBox.Show("ERROR. THE AMOUNT OF WITHOLDINGS ($" & decTotalTax.ToString("N2") & ") EXCEEDS THE GROSS PAY.")
                End If
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("ERROR. YOU HAVE EXCEEDED THE ALLOWABLE NUMBER OF EMPLOYEES.")
            End if
```

And then integer k would obviously be the value you do whatever with. If not that, it will definitely be something very similar.

Comment: I thought about writing it that way but what if the EmployeeID isn't a single integer between 0 and 10? What if it's a six or seven digit number? How do I account for that?